# insert hyperlink in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to display a link in a php document. the data is stored in  mysql. I have stored the url in the field course_url.

i can get the page to show the hyperlink asd a plain text but want it to show ashyperlink with "Click Here" anchor text. The coding i got so far is:

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mentertraining");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$query = "SELECT `coursedates`.`coursedate_id`,`coursedates`.`course_id`,`coursedates`.`date1`,`courses`.`course_title`,`courses`.`course_url`,`courses`.`no_of_days` FROM coursedates\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN `mentertraining`.`courses` ON `coursedates`.`course_id` = `courses`.`course_id` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Course Title</th><th>Course Date</th><th>No of Days</th><th>Course URL</th></tr>";

while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  $date = new DateTime($row['date1']);
    $row['date1'] = $date->format('d/m/Y');

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['course_title'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['date1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['no_of_days'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>""<a href=" . $row['course_url'] .  >"'Click Her'"</a>""</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your echo is malformed on this line:

```
echo "<td>""<a href=" . $row['course_url'] .  >"'Click Her'"</a>""</td>";
```

It should be:

```
echo "<td><a href='" . $row['course_url'] .  "'>Click Here</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong `"'` quotations

```
while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  $date = new DateTime($row['date1']);
    $row['date1'] = $date->format('d/m/Y');

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['course_title'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['date1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['no_of_days'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='" . $row['course_url'] ."'>Click Her</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```